# generating diffrent tone in a time interval in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, ringtone

how to generate continuous tone with below conditions as i only able to create the tone from time 0 to 1. Ho to continuous generate it?
Create a 3 second signal containing three tones; Tone 220 Hz for 0 < t < 1 Tone 300 Hz for 1 < t < 2 Tone 440 Hz for 2 < t < 3
using s=sin(2*pi*t) and sampling frequency of 8192 Hz

```
Fs = 8192;
T = 1/Fs;                                             

t = 0:T:1;
t1=1:T:2;
t2=2:T:3;
y = sin(2*pi*200*t); 
hold on;
y = sin(2*pi*300*t1);
hold on;
y = sin(2*pi*440*t2); 
hold on;                         
plot(t,y);           
xlabel('t');                              
ylabel('Amplitude');
```

Thanks

Comment: hi, as above is the code i had tried, i onli manage to get an interval of time.

Comment: hmm..not reali the one i want..i was ask to create a tone with the specification as this...Tone 220 Hz for 0 < t < 1 Tone 300 Hz for 1 < t < 2 Tone 440 Hz for 2 < t < 3 using s=sin(2*pi*t) and sampling frequency of 8192 Hz..but i nt manage to create any tone tat can fit in..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean this?

```
Fs = 8192;
T = 1/Fs;                                             

t1 = 0:T:1;
t2=1:T:2;
t3=2:T:3;
y1 = sin(2*pi*200*t); 
y2 = sin(2*pi*300*t1);
y3 = sin(2*pi*440*t2);                          
plot(t1,y1,t2,y2,t3,y3);           
xlabel('t');                              
ylabel('Amplitude');
```

If so, and you want the data to be in two arrays do the next also

```
t=horzcat(t1,t2,t3);
y=horzcat(y1,y2,y3);
```

I am not 100% sure if this is what you want, if not, please correct me

Comment: hmm..not reali the one i want..i was ask to create a tone with the specification as this...Tone 220 Hz for 0 < t < 1 Tone 300 Hz for 1 < t < 2 Tone 440 Hz for 2 < t < 3 using s=sin(2*pi*t) and sampling frequency of 8192 Hz..but i nt manage to create any tone tat can fit in..

Comment: i dont get it yet... the signal I created has a sinusoidal tone of 200HZ from 0 to 1, then 300 from 1 to 2 and 440 from 2 to 3. The time points are generated with the frequenzy you wanted. What is exactly what you want? @KaeBinAmbrose

Comment: @KaeBinAmbrose no problem! here we are for whatever you want!

Comment: if i wan add in random noise with zero means and variance of 1 i use tis formula..
y=x+2*randn(size(t))
i able to generate the random noise..but hw to put into the tone signal?

Comment: just add it. As you created y_noise=x+2*randn(size(t,1)) you can sum it directly to y by= y=y+y_noise. @KaeBinAmbrose

Comment: Thanks alot...^^... now i left to create the IIR filter to filter out the frequency i wan...thanks

Comment: @KaeBinAmbrose this may help you http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/signal/ug/iir-filter-design.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x` is a Nx1 vector containing the tone for 1 second, you can replicate this to become a tone for 3 seconds:

```
x_long = repmat(x,3,1)
```

Comment: but i want to have 3 different tones in each interval...how to apply in that?